# PHP: SQL update with PDO doesn't work. Error: "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Tags: php, pdo

Here below you can see my code.

I re-read my code many times and I can't see the error.

The error is

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

My code below (the error occurs at the execution of the query inside the variable $sqlUpUser).

```
<?php

require '../shared/geolocation.php';

$user="db686186_adm";
$pass="#+-7en!Z";



try{


$coordinates = getCoordinates($adress); 


if($coordinates["geolocationSuccessful"]){

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=nhl-mysqlw01;dbname=db686186', $user, $pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sqlUpUser = "UPDATE users SET "
        . "country=:country, "
        . "adress=:adress, "
        . "email=:email, "
        . "phone=:phone, "
        . "skype=:skype, "
        . "lat=:lat, "
        . "`long`=:long "
        . "WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id'];


    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sqlUpUser); 


    $stmt->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':adress', $adress, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':skype', $skype,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lat', $coordinates["latitude"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':long', $coordinates["longitude"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
 }else{

   $_SESSION["emailExist"] = constant($coordinates["errorMessage"]); 
    header("Location:/profile/");
    return;
}
}catch(Exception $e){
    printf($e->getMessage());
}


$dbh = null;
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I don't think so. I have other queries with $_SESSION['id'] concatenated in this way and there is no error there. 
The issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure `lat` and `long` are strings?

Comment: Why the backticks on Long? . "`long`=:long "

Comment: @MatthewPage it's a reserved keyword

Comment: @RamRaider it is correct. The function getCoordinates() succesufully returns the data.
However, keep in mind that in PHP a not initialized variable is null (not an error) and you can use the value null in a query.

If the field is not NULLABLE, you will get an other error.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no, lat and long are float numbers, but I read that with float numbers you have to use PDO::PARAM_STR. There is not PDO::PARAM_FLOAT or something similar.
Keep in mind that in other parts of the software there is an insert query where lat and long are used with PDO::PARAM_STR and it works.

Comment: just a guess... what if you change the name of the token `:long` both in the query string and `bindParam` (ex. to `lngt`) ? Maybe PDO doesn't recognize `:long` as a token being `long` a reserved keyword

Comment: @Paolo I've just tried. The query still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe one of the bindParams is failing? The call returns true/false, so check each one to see what's being returned.

Comment: I've just realized that the error message comes from an other part of the code. 
My question should be deleted, because the code above works well.

Sorry too all people who lost time for a non-problem.

Comment: @Learjet45 even though it works you may want to peek at my answer and how it handles your data. You may find it easier to understand and work with.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a variable that you don't really need, `$sqlUpUser` and manually binding things let PHP and PDO take care things.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE users SET
        country=:country,
        adress=:adress,
        email=:email,
        phone=:phone,
        skype=:skype,
        lat=:lat,
        `long`=:long
        WHERE id=' . $_SESSION['id']
);

$stmt->execute([':country' => $country ,
                ':adress'  => $adress  ,
                ':email'   => $email   ,
                ':phone'   => $phone   ,
                ':skype'   => $skype   ,
                ':lat'     => $coordinates["latitude"] ,
                ':long'    => $coordinates["longitude"]
                ]
);
```